# QT Pyside 6 - QT Quick Backend Software Adaptation Causing Black Bars & Other Graphical Errors

Tags: qml, pyside6, pyqt6

For compatibility reasons, my QT for Python project needs to use the QT_QUICK_BACKEND software adaptation. However, this is causing random black lines and boxes to appear on my app (examples below).

[image: Example]

If I change the scene graph renderer to the default renderer, these graphical glitches go away. However, that's not a solution available to me. These glitches are most prevalent after actions that update the frontend, such as scrolling or using a combo box. Does anyone know what causes these graphical glitches, and what can be done to mitigate it outside of changing the scene graph renderer?

Comment: We need more details, as your current description is too broad to understand the issue. For instance, OS/PySide versions, and possibly a [mre].